# How do I delete events in shotwell?

Tags: photo-management, shotwell

I want to use shotwell to manage my photos (along with other power apps like F-Spot and Digicam), for various reasons, but I have one issue. I can't figure out how to delete events. Is this possible (meaning I'm missing something) or is it not a part of the feature set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature has been requested on the Shotwell [mailing list](http://lists.yorba.org/pipermail/shotwell/2010-October/001123.html):

> > First and foremost, I think there definitely should be a way to "delete"
> >     events, or assign photos to "no event". Importing a folder of ~1000
> >     "miscellaneous" photos collected over a year creates about 30-50 events,
> >     which is a bit ridiculous; it defeats the purpose of events matching
> >     actual events and not "days", so I'd really like a way to unassign
> >     photos from events to get a better bird-eye's view of the "important"
> >     pictures among the mess.
>
> This has been ticketed: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2665

This feature has not yet been added, but could be in the future.

Comment: thanks. I was going to try to convince someone else to use it, but that will have to wait :D

Comment: The links are dead, the ticket URL is now https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716753

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ideal solution but you can delete data and thumbs folders in /home/[local]/.shotwell folder for a fresh start.
I second the need for a native edit of events in shotwell.

Comment: Yeah, well deleting everything isn't really a good way to go, but it could work in extreme situations.